# Power BI Measure to calculate percentage which changes with filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a visualisation from a dataset which shows percentages that change accordingly when filters are used.

I have a dataset like the below but with over 1 million rows of data covering 18 months. All the fields are text except Month which is a date and SUMofAPPTS which is numerical.

```
SUPP    GEOG1   MODE    STATUS  TYPE    TIME    Month   Day    SUMofAPPTS
AA  00D Face    Att     1       1       Day     2018-06 Sun    12
AA  00D Face    Att     1       1       Day     2018-06 Mon    119
AA  00D Face    Att     1       4       Unk     2018-06 Tues   98
BB  00D Tel     DNA     2       1       Day     2018-06 Weds   98
BB  00D Online  DNA     3       1       Day     2018-06 Thurs  126
CC  00D Face    DNA     1       2       Day     2018-07 Sun    8
```

I would like a measure which calculates the percentage of `SUMofAPPTS` by `Day` and `MODE` (and the same but for `STATUS`, `TYPE` and `TIME`) which changes when filters are placed on the other fields.

So I think I need to make this simple calculation (which would work in a column if I just wanted to know the percentage per row of the whole dataset) more dynamic so that it works when I filter the data:

```
PERCENT = 'dataset'[SUMofAPPTS]/SUM('dataset'[SUMofAPPTS])
```

The end result will be a stacked bar chart with the following attributes:

- Day as the Axis
- PERCENT as the Value
- MODE, STATUS, TYPE or TIME as the Legend
- Ability to filter by one, many or all of the fields except Day and SUMofAPPTS

Comment: Can you define denominator a bit better? A percent of what - entire dataset? Examples of the desired outcome would be helpful.

Comment: Percent of the sum of SUMofAPPTS for the filtered dataset. So if I filtered by Month and selected 2018-06 then SUMofAPPTS(per Day) / sum(SUMofAPPTS) for 2018-06. And if I selected multiple months then the denominator would be the sum of SUMofAPPTS in all those months. I would like to be able to filter by multiple fields at a time and have the denominator be the sum of SUMofAPPTS for all rows of data which are selected by that filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a measure for aggregating SUMofAPPTS:

```
Total APPTS = SUM(Data[SUMofAPPTS])
```

Second, create a measure for the percentage:

```
APPTS % of Selected 
= DIVIDE(
   [Total APPTS],
   CALCULATE([Total APPTS], ALLSELECTED()))
```

This measure recalculates [Total APPTS] ignoring all filters except those selected by a user (on slicers etc).

Result:

[image]

after selections:

[image]

**Edit**

If you need to breakdown by Day (or any other field), you can re-introduce filters like this:

```
APPTS % of Selected 
= DIVIDE(
   [Total APPTS],
   CALCULATE([Total APPTS], ALLSELECTED(), VALUES(Data[Day])))
```

Comment: Hi @RADO, thanks but this only provides the percentage for all Days together so that when I create a visualisation with Day as the y axis and APPTS % of Selected as the x axis it appears as less than 100% per Day, I would like to see the percentage breakdown by Day. Is there a way to adapt what you provided for this?