# Percentage Based on Same Field Value

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have a flat table like this:

| Date | UserID | Reason | Productive? | TotalDuration | Group | Channel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-20 | A | Break | false | 00:13:21 | Foo | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | A | O.Work | true | 07:02:29 | Foo | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | A | Shift | - | 07:27:32 | Foo | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | A | V.Work | true | 00:10:08 | Foo | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | B | Break | false | 00:15:41 | Foo | #S |
| 2022-03-20 | B | Meeting | false | 00:00:26 | Foo | #S |
| 2022-03-20 | B | OU.Work | true | 00:03:36 | Foo | #S |
| 2022-03-20 | B | Shift | - | 06:03:41 | Foo | #S |
| 2022-03-20 | B | V.Work | true | 00:42:38 | Foo | #S |
| 2022-03-20 | C | Break | false | 00:30:01 | Bar | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | C | O.Work | false | 00:04:14 | Bar | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | C | OU.Work | true | 00:35:39 | Bar | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | C | Shift | - | 06:09:48 | Bar | #E |
| 2022-03-20 | C | V.Work | true | 01:37:47 | Bar | #E |

I want to create a pivotable that calculates the percentage of each `Reason` based on the `Shift` value of the same column.
In other words `Reason[Value]` divided by `Reason[Shift]`.

Such pivotable will be filtered by Productive and Reason but want to have the flexibility to use any other field as filter as well.

[image: Pivotable]

I think my best option would be some DAX measures [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272781/power-bi-measure-to-calculate-percentage-which-changes-with-filters) but I just can't make it work.

I'm open to all solution within Excel toolkit (VBA, PQ, DAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `Table1` you can use the following `DAX`

### Sum of Total Duration

```
Sum of Total Duration = 
sum(Table1[TotalDuration])
```

### Sum of Total Duration

```
Percent Total Duration =
VAR ValueswithoutShift =
    CALCULATE (
        [Sum Total Duration],
        Table1[Reason] <> "Shift",
        VALUES ( Table1[Reason] )
    )
VAR Shift =
    CALCULATE (
        [Sum Total Duration],
        Table1[Reason] = "Shift",
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[UserID] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( ValueswithoutShift, Shift )
```

## Output

I'm using `UserID`, `Productive?` and `Reason` as Rows.
`Sum Total Duration` and `Percent Total Duration` as Values.

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Wasn't able to make it work by myself. I just tried all configurations that I might need by changing/adding "ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[UserID] )" on your function. Thank a lot.